# ngx-formly json powered use decimal pipe

Tags: decimal, angular2-forms

To persist form configuration in a database for a new Angular project I found  [this](https://stackblitz.com/angular/mrxagkdpmyd?file=src%2Fassets%2Fjson-powered%2Fuser-form.json) example with Angular2 Formly.

I started by using a bootstrap template and could quite easily generate fields with min max values etc

Now i would like to setup input elements that could hold only numbers and also would persist to use a certain (variable) amount of decimals. and for this i created the folowing custom type component with an other [this](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/addons) Angular Text-mask addon:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FieldType } from '@ngx-formly/core';
import createNumberMask from 'text-mask-addons/dist/createNumberMask';


@Component({
  selector: 'formly-field-decimal-input',
  template: `
   <div class="form-group">
   <label class="form-control-label control-label">
   {{ to.label }}
 </label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" [textMask]="{mask: numberMask}" [formControl]="formControl" [formlyAttributes]="field">
   </div>
 `,
})


export class FormlyFieldDecimalInput extends FieldType {
  public numberMask = createNumberMask({
    prefix: '',
    suffix: '',
    includeThousandsSeparator: false,
    allowDecimal: true,
    decimalSymbol: '.',
    decimalLimit: 1,
    integerLimit: null,
    requireDecimal: true,
    allowNegative: false,
    allowLeadingZeroes: false
  });
}
```

I call this type through json like this:

```
[
  {
    "key": "decimal",
    "type": "decimal",
    "templateOptions": {
      "label": "Custom Type for 1 Decimal mask (needs calculated completion onBlur)",
      "placeholder": "Eg: 18.3",
      "decimalLimit": 1
    }
  }
]
```

This masks the input to help to type the right format.
What i can't seem to achieve is first how to make the decimalLimit dynamic so that i can use one type for different decimal values and second and how do i auto generate eg 1.0 when the user only inputs 1

Comment: in regular JavaScript I would use .toFixed(d)  where is the number of decimals required, but than you still need to be able to set the value of the input with the new value and I have no clue how to do that in with formly